# The roots of $z^2+4\sqrt2z-8\sqrt3i$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Once I have found the roots of the discriminant, how do I use them to solve? The $\pm$ is throwing me off.

> **M11** Solve the quadratic equation $z^2+4\sqrt2z-8\sqrt3i=0$ and mark the points representing the two roots, $z_1$ and $z_2$, on an Argand diagram. ($i^2=-1$ as usual.) [20 marks]

Comment: You also failed to explain why someone should bother studying your problem when you don't even put some effort into grammar and orthography. Just sayin'

Comment: I apologise but I am slight dyslexic so I find it hard to put what I write into words, I also tend to miss word out not on purpose I do actually try to read through my stuff but I always miss stuff out. And I did say I would post my solutions up which I tried to do by photo but I got a message I dont have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the discriminant is $\Delta=32+32\sqrt{3}i=64e^{i\pi/3}$ (with $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$).

Hence the solutions are:
$$z_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}(-4\sqrt{2}\pm \sqrt{\Delta})
=\frac{1}{2}(-4\sqrt{2}\pm 8e^{i\pi/6})=-2\sqrt{2}\pm 4e^{i\pi/6},$$
that is
$$z_1=-2\sqrt{2}+4e^{i\pi/6}=2(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+2i,\;
z_2=-2\sqrt{2}-4e^{i\pi/6}=-2(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})-2i.$$

Comment: Ah thank you. I did have the root but got my self confuse of the plus minus. Once again thank you.